# Invalid Topology Exception error while submitting a topology

Tags: java, apache-storm

While working on my first Storm Topology that is based on reading Apache file and process it, I am getting weird error when submitting Topology:

```
6044 [main] WARN  backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus - Topology submission exception. (topology name='apachelog') #<InvalidTopologyException InvalidTopologyException(msg:Component: [lineBolt] subscribes from non-existent component [line])>
6051 [main] ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn - Thread Thread[main,5,main] died
backtype.storm.generated.InvalidTopologyException: null
    at backtype.storm.daemon.common$validate_structure_BANG_.invoke(common.clj:151) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.common$system_topology_BANG_.invoke(common.clj:287) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$fn__5528$exec_fn__1229__auto__$reify__5541.submitTopologyWithOpts(nimbus.clj:932) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$fn__5528$exec_fn__1229__auto__$reify__5541.submitTopology(nimbus.clj:950) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.testing$submit_local_topology.invoke(testing.clj:236) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.LocalCluster$_submitTopology.invoke(LocalCluster.clj:19) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.LocalCluster.submitTopology(Unknown Source) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at storm.starter.ApacheAccessLogTopology.main(ApacheAccessLogTopology.java:68) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120) ~[idea_rt.jar:na]
```

**My Sprout file**

```
public class LogReaderSpout extends BaseRichSpout
{
    private SpoutOutputCollector _collector;
    private String filePath = "access_log";

    @Override
    public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector)
    {
        _collector = collector;
    }

    @Override
    public void nextTuple()
    {
        Utils.sleep(100);
        String line = null;
        try
        {
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            while((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if(line!=null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    _collector.emit(new Values(line));
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Emitting Next Tuple..");
    }

    @Override
    public void ack(Object id)
    {
        System.out.println("Ack with ID: "+id);
    }

    @Override
    public void fail(Object id)
    {
        System.out.println("Fail with ID: "+id);
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("line"));
    }
}
```

**Topology**

```
package storm.starter;
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.StormSubmitter;
import backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichBolt;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;
import backtype.storm.utils.Utils;
import storm.starter.spout.LogReaderSpout;

import java.util.Map;

public class ApacheAccessLogTopology
{
    public static class LineBolt extends BaseRichBolt
    {
        OutputCollector _collector;

        @Override
        public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector)
        {
            _collector = collector;
        }

        @Override
        public void execute(Tuple tuple)
        {
            //ALL PROCESSING will take place here on tuple(in our case Line here)
            _collector.emit(tuple, new Values(tuple.getString(0) + "???"));
            _collector.ack(tuple);
        }

        @Override
        public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer)
        {
            declarer.declare(new Fields("line"));
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("lineSpout", new LogReaderSpout(),2);
        builder.setBolt("lineBolt", new LineBolt(),2).shuffleGrouping("line");

        Config conf = new Config();
        conf.setDebug(true);

        if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
            conf.setNumWorkers(2);

            StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology());
        }
        else {

            LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
            cluster.submitTopology("apachelog", conf, builder.createTopology());
            Utils.sleep(10000);
            cluster.killTopology("apachelog");
            cluster.shutdown();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: For anyone else encountering the invalid topology exception. If this is your topology and all the names are correct: `Spout1--emit-->Bolt1---->Bolt2`. You'll get the exception if your Bolt1 is not emitting any tuples.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your topology definition isn't valid. You should have:

```
builder.setBolt("lineBolt", new LineBolt(),2).shuffleGrouping("lineSpout");
```

Comment: You were right. Can you please explain why this worked? As far as I learnt so far, Shuffle means to group data based on input mentioned in parameter. What it's telling here?

Comment: @Volatil3 You need to tell the bolt the data source for it. Otherwise how it is supposed to know what to process? In your case, the bolt wasn't able to get its data because the there is no spout named 'line'

Comment: Ah.. so *lineSpout* is kind of alias referring the source that is being consumed. Thanks

Comment: @Volatil3 You defined your spout to have that name. This line is doing so:  builder.setSpout("lineSpout", new LogReaderSpout(),2);

Comment: On running example it shows like:  Emitting: lineSpout *The String to be emitted**.  How is it possible to emit from my bolt; *lineBolt* in my scenario? or it is only possible if I add another bolt/Spout and subscribe my previous stream to it?

Comment: @Volatil3 Have you checked your source code? Your bolt is emitting

Answer (score 3):

Faced same problem as above and below is my exception

```
Topology submission exception. (topology name='Getting-Started-Toplogie') <InvalidTopologyException InvalidTopologyException(msg:Component: [Record-normalizertt] subscribes from non-existent stream: [default] of component [Rreader])>
```

And here is my solution this worked to me.

Declare below statement in method declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) in your spout or bolt class.

```
declarer.declare(new Fields("line"));
```

Finally your method should be as below in your spout or bolt class.

```
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    declarer.declare(new Fields("line"));

    }
```